# Is there smart way to parse xml to list?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

There is xml file, which have next structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myobjectlist objectCount = "3">
    <myobject Number = "0" Name="My First Object" MyChildObectsCount = "2">
        <intProp>5</intProp>
        <stringProp>Str1</stringProp>
        <doubleProp>35.1</doubleProp>
        <MyChildObj Number = "100" Name = "My first child object">
            <childIntProp>1</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr1</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
        <MyChildObj Number = "120" Name = "My child object">
            <childIntProp>15</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr2</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
    </myobject>
    <myobject Number = "145" Name="My second Object" MyChildObectsCount = "1">
        <intProp>96</intProp>
        <stringProp>Str2</stringProp>
        <doubleProp>+Inf</doubleProp>
        <MyChildObj Number = "250" Name = "This's child object">
            <childIntProp>62</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr3</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
    </myobject>
    <myobject Number = "261" Name="My last Object" MyChildObectsCount = "3">
        <intProp>9</intProp>
        <stringProp>Str45</stringProp>
        <doubleProp>1.6449635e+07</doubleProp>
        <MyChildObj Number = "150" Name = "Almost last child object">
            <childIntProp>-1</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr41</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
        <MyChildObj Number = "680" Name = "Prelast child object">
            <childIntProp>72</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr42</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
        <MyChildObj Number = "127" Name = "Last child object">
            <childIntProp>64</childIntProp>
            <childStringProp>CStr222</childStringProp>
        </MyChildObj>
    </myobject>
</myobjectlist>
```

I've tried to use XMLSerializer, but how I found out it can't deserialize to list, all objects of the list will be the first object of deserializable xml, so me result list will consist ObjCount of 0th obj.

I've created classes -- enteties of xml objects, let's say

```
public class MyObject{
    int Number;
    string Name;
    int IntProp;
    string stringProp;
    double doubleProp;
    List<MyChildObject> myChildObjects;
}

public class MyChildObject{
    int Number;
    string Name;
    int childIntProp;
    string childStringProp;
}
```

I need to get `List<MyObject>` from XML file, but I do not want to parse it node by node. Is there smart way to do it?

**UPDATE**

And here, what I got: [Empty list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0zIZ.png)

Comment: Can you calrify what you mean by "all objects of the list will be the first object of deserializable xml"?

Comment: You ***will*** need to deserialize it one way or another

Comment: And please provide valid XML and valid C# classes. You know, stuff that compiles and XML that can be read by an XML parser. It would make understanding your question and helping you orders of magnitude easier for us.

Comment: ^^ Or put differently: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: I've changed examples trying to correspond to minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Here is also good info: 1) https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/deserializing-xml-into-a-list-or-array-of-objects

2) https://www.aspneto.com/how-deserialize-xml-document-asp-net-c-vb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you annotate your data model like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "myobjectlist")]
public class MyObjectList
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "objectCount")]
    public string ObjectCount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "myobject")]
    public List<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}
```

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "myobject")]
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MyChildObectsCount")]
    public string MyChildObjectsCount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "intProp")]
    public string IntProp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "stringProp")]
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "doubleProp")]
    public string DoubleProp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MyChildObj")]
    public List<MyChildObject> MyChildObjects { get; set; }
}
```

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MyChildObj")]
public class MyChildObject
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "childIntProp")]
    public string ChildIntProp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "childStringProp")]
    public string ChildStringProp { get; set; }
}
```

The the deseralization logic is this simple:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("sample.xml"));
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObjectList));
var data = (MyObjectList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

[image: deserialization works]

---

**UPDATE #2**

If you need to handle

- `+Inf` as `float.PositiveInfinity`
- `-Inf` as `float.NegativeInfinity`

then you need to change the text of the `<doubleProp>`. One way to do this is the following:

```
var malformedXml = File.ReadAllText("sample.xml");
var fixedXml = malformedXml
    .Replace("<doubleProp>+Inf</doubleProp>", "<doubleProp>Infinity</doubleProp>")
    .Replace("<doubleProp>-Inf</doubleProp>", "<doubleProp>-Infinity</doubleProp>");

var fixedXmlStream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(fixedXmlStream);
writer.Write(fixedXml);
writer.Flush();
fixedXmlStream.Position = 0;
var reader = new StreamReader(fixedXmlStream);
```

Comment: And this doesn't work. Here's the link, where it said. And also I've tried to do it in this way. There're no error, but the list is empty. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0

Comment: @ddg It does deserialize the xml without any problem, please see my screenshot about the watch window. Which list is empty in your case?

Comment: @(Peter Csala)
I've added screenshot. For some reason, my list is empty.

Comment: @ddg In your shared image the `PgnCount` is `"671"`. In your question there is nothing related to `PgnCount` and `"671"`. Please evaluate my proposed solution against your posted xml.

Comment: @ddg Please bear in mind that xml deserialization is case sensitive. Which means that if you have an xml node with name `myobject` then the related `ElementName` must be the same. If you have provided anything else (like `myObject`, `myobjects`, `MyObject`)  then the deserailizer won't be able to populate that property with the related xml data.

Comment: Ok, I've found my mistake, but there's still a problem. I need float/double at double prop, not string. If I change string to float/double an error comes out: "There is an error in XML document (20, 6)" and "Input string was not in a correct format.
". 

If I parse manually there's no such problem, cause I can fill in "doubleProp = Single.PositiveInfinity".

Comment: @ddg You have 3 `doubleProp` values: `35.1`, `+Inf`, `1.6449635e+07`. The first and the last can be parsed as float. On the other hand the `+Inf` can't. So, the problem comes from the source data.

Comment: If I parse it manually, I do next:
```C#
xr.Read();  //xr is XmlTextReader
try{
    doubleProp = float.Parse(xr.Value.Replace('.', ','));
}
catch {
   doubleProp = Single.PositiveInfinity;
}
```

Comment: @ddg Yes exactly, you have an explicit fallback logic. But if I remember correctly this requirement was not part of your question.

Comment: It wasn't when I had posted this question without minimal reproducible example, but when I had added it, this requirement had became part of my question.

Comment: @ddg I've extended my post to handle `+Inf`. Please check it.